# Как написать sql запрос, объединяющий две таблицы?

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте!

Есть две таблицы, одна с данными, другая будет заполняться позже... Надо sql запросом соединить эти две таблицы, что б данные из заполненной таблицы отображались, а вторую можно было б заполнять вручную. Как это сделать?

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 2):

Ещё могу предложить такой вариант (выборка будет произведена так, словно это одна таблица):

```
SELECT id_one AS id, name, null AS none FROM [Table 1] WHERE ...
UNION ALL -- ALL тут означает «выбрать даже если есть повторения»
SELECT id_two AS id, name, some_field AS none FROM [Table 2] WHERE ...
```

Количество, типы и названия (хотя бы как псевдоним после AS) полей в выборках должны совпадать. Актуально для Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Например как-то так:

```
Select *
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.Id=t2.Table1Id
```

Где t1.Id первичный ключ в первой таблице, а t2.TableId - внешний ключ во второй таблице.

Answer (score 1):

О типах соединений можно почитать [здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/en/book_explicit_join_operations.html).